# MapBox: show marker's info window without access to a MapView

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm using the Android MapBox SDK, and I want to show the info window for a marker that I've created.  `showInfoWindow` as far as I can tell is the only way to do this.  The problem is it requires both a `MapBoxMap`, which I have, and a `MapView`, which I do not.  I'm using `MapFragment`, and I don't see any way to get a `MapView` instance.  It looks to me like this is a gap in the SDK but I'm hoping someone has a solution.

I already hit another critical problem preventing me from using a `MapView` (issue raised with MapBox) and now this is critical functionality for my app that I can't do without a `MapView` so I'm thinking I may have to abandon MapBox altogether.  :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Marker.showInfoWindow` you need to select the marker through:

`mapboxMap.selectMarker(Marker marker)`

This will not only show the InfoWindow but will also manage the selected state.

Comment: I actually got MapView working so I don't know if this works but maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: I can only advice you to use selectMarker as noted, this manages selection state correctly

Comment: see javadoc of Marker#showInfoWindow: Do not use this method, used internally by the SDK. Use {@link MapboxMap#selectMarker(Marker)}
if you want to programmatically display the markers info window.

Comment: Seems problematic to have a method that isn't intended for use outside the library to be marked public.  `selectMarker` does work though.